# Less Resources not Compiling Play 2.3.7

Tags: css, scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I am trying to compile *.less resources from my `assets/stylesheets/` directory. I have one file contained in this directory, which is `masterpage.less`.

I have added the sbt plugin for less
`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")` in my `plugins.sbt` file.

The [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/AssetsLess) says:

> Compilable assets in Play must be defined in the app/assets directory.
>   They are handled by the build process, and LESS sources are compiled
>   into standard CSS files. The generated CSS files are distributed as
>   standard resources into the same public/ folder as the unmanaged
>   assets, meaning that there is no difference in the way you use them
>   once compiled.

Which I am doing, so I am confused as to why my resources are not being compiled into `public/`

Here are the routes I have:

```
GET    /assets/*file    controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
GET    /vassets/*file   controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
GET    /webjars/*file   controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file)
```

This is how I am trying to link the css page in my html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/masterpage.css")"/>
```

and lastly, here is the error I am getting in my console:

```
 GET http://localhost:9000/assets/masterpage.css
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, sbt-less only looks for a file called `main.less`. If you want to use a different file, you have to indicate it in build.sbt.

```
includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "masterpage.less"
```

If you want to include all LESS files, use a wildcard:

```
includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "*.less"
```

This is not the default because you normally import LESS files from your `main.less`.

Comment: So this worked, but the passage of text in the OP seems to be misleading. I interpreted that to mean that ANY `*.less` file in the `app/assets` directory would be compiled. If I have 100 `less` files I would have t oinclude them all in that filter?

Comment: You would typically import them from your main.less so you have a single .js output file. Or use wildcards.